# asynchronous messaging/notifications for real time feed back to users

Tags: php, python, ruby, node.js, social-networking

Looking for some advice and general opinion.

Im looking to build a notification system for a site to message users on at certain times and events.

So for example when a new blog post is added to the site, any user that is logged onto the system will get a visual notification (A bit like when someone comments on your status on facebook) There will also need to be some persistence there so that users who are not logged in will get the notification once they return to the site.

Anyway Im look for any advice Re: tech/language/framework, on the real time/asyn nature of how this would work.

The only dependency/restriction is that the components must be open source, but other then that the function can be built in anything (node/python/pure javascript solution/php etc)

N.B I am looking at [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) as a possible option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) connecting to html5 websockets that fail over to sockjs if the browser doesn't [implement websockets](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/13/sockjs-websocket-emulation/).

rabbitmq has python, ruby, erlang. hell, there's a straight c plug in.

Comment: Think this might be the way to go as seems there are ports for pretty much every language. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Faye is a good choice.
You may also want to look at vertx.io if you need something more sophisticated but scalable.